# sitemap.xml 404 error on one server, not on another?

Tags: html, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I'm having a problem with my sitemap. I know I strictly don't need a site map as my site in question is only a single page, but when reading on the web some people say it's not necessary and other say it is, but that's by the by!

I created my sitemap manually and uploaded to a test server, everything was working well. I uploaded it onto the actual server and thought all would be fine. I run woorank's website review and it says that the sitemap doesn't exist. I did the woorank test on the test server and it found the server.

If I try and browse to the [sitemap](https://xxxxxx.co.uk/sitemap.xml) on the server I get a 404 error saying the file isn't found. Browse to the [sitemap](https://xxxxxx.com/sitemap.xml) on the test server, displays it fine!

Thought it might have been the way I created, so used https://www.xml-sitemaps.com to create the sitemap, same issue.

Checked that the file is a text file.

Hostinger, the hosting company, says there shouldn't be an issue.

This is the sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-12-10T21:38:07+00:00</lastmod>
</url>


</urlset>
```

Any body have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Image of files in folder as requested

[image: Files in folder]

Comment: can you share hosting file manager list view. Because this 404 error is not xml not support or other error related to xml. Its hosting default page which return 404 page.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean? Do you want to see the list files on the server?

Comment: yes that view or image of that server. also which server you are using ? is apache or tomcat or iis  ?

Comment: Thanks, unsure how to add an image to the comment so edited the main question. it is Apache I believe in parallel with NGINX, what ever that is!

Comment: can you try creating one file "sample.txt" and upload it see if you able to view or not ? also check fine name is there trailing space left and right ?

Comment: robots.txt works fine. rename the sitemap to sitemap.txt and it displays fine. Not preeding or trailing spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204040/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-neil-white).

Comment: your testing server and production server is same ? check if any configuration you may be missing if server is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. Whilst trying to solve another issue, in my .htaccess file I came across some lines that were mentioning xml, some I commented them out and vola! Access to my xml file again!